# Drools, Update error: handle not found for object

Tags: drools

Here's my rule

```
rule "ICodes in HISTORY" 
@filename("ORDERING.drl")
ruleflow-group "ORDERING_MAIN" 
lock-on-active true
salience 5000
when
    icodeColl:  ArrayList (size > 0) from collect ( CodeFact( traceSegments contains RuleConstant.Seg.H, position == null, type == RuleConstant.CodeSource.I) )

    ccodeColl:  ArrayList (size >= 0) from collect ( CodeFact( type == RuleConstant.CodeSource.C) )

    orderHier:  OrderHierarchy( identifier == 
            RuleConstant.ReferenceTables.IHIER)
    theCase:    CaseFact()
then
    ArrayList hOrderedIcodes= orderHier.order(icodeColl, ccodeColl);

    for (int i=0; i<hOrderedIcodes.size(); i++) {
        CodeFact icode = (CodeFact)hOrderedIcodes.get(i);
        int positionCount = theCase.getPositionCount();

        icode.setPosition( BigInteger.valueOf( positionCount ) );
        theCase.incrementPosition();

        update( icode);
    }
end
```

And here's the error I get. I know that CodeFact is being retracted in another rule, but this is crazy to me that I would have gobbled it up in the when clause but it's not available for update in the then clause.

> org.drools.FactException: Update error: handle not found for object:
>   CodeFact@2a501b38 {xxx.xxx, 1, 1.0}.
>   Is it in the working memory?

Comment: Could be a bug. Create a full set of Java and DRL files necessary for reproducing the problem and add all of it to your question, and make sure to mention the Drools version.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone running into this problem still, 11 months later like I did:
I have been working on a slightly older project using drools and we always ran it using Java 7. I got this error after trying to run our project with Java 8. Hopefully this helps someone because I couldn't find a straight answer from googling. This was just my experience with this error, hopefully it is the cause of yours!